# How to change which Python is used when opening platformio-ide-terminal in Atom on macOS

Tags: python, terminal, atom-editor

I am trying to use the "platformio-ide-terminal" package in Atom, on macOS, to open terminals within Atom.

The issue is, the terminal in Atom does not use my Anaconda Python, and thus does not have access to packages I installed using Anaconda. Typing

```
which python
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/python
```

in platformio-ide-terminal and

```
/Users/.../anaconda3/bin/python
```

in the terminal.

Typing

```
which python3
```

in platformio-ide-terminal returns

```
/Users/.../anaconda3/bin/python3
```

I am very troubled about all these different Pythons coexisting on my computer, and a general explanation about how this works would also be very welcome.

I would also like to use the same version of Python in Atom. How can I do this?

Comment: Multiple versions of a language are not an issue because we often want to test backwards compatibility, except they consume extra disk space, as long as you know what you're doing. I'd recommend looking into any of the Python sandbox/virtual applications to manage your Python environments, then you'll be in a position to tell Atom and the terminal package which Python you what to use at any particular time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using IDEs rather than text editors. Pycharm offers a lot of clarity on the version of Python you are using: you can choose the exact directory with the version of Python you want to use ([by setting an interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)), and then run / debug the project from Pycharm using this version of Python. Then, I deleted other directories with unused versions of Python to save the space.